# Show that the set of all groups is uncountable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Show that the set of all groups is uncountable.

I think we can consider group $ ( \Bbb{R} ,+)$ and $<x>$ (generated sub group with $x)$,$x,y \in (0,1] $ now $\{<x> \cap  <y> \cap (0,1] \} $= finite set and $\cup_{x \in (0,1]} \{<x> \cap (0,1] \} =(0,1]$ and (0,1] is uncountable and implys that the set of all groups is uncountable. Is it true ?

Comment: I assume the question would be that the set of all isomorphism classes of groups is uncountable. Otherwise, you can just take an uncountable set $X$ and to every $x \in X$ associate the trivial one-element group $\{ x \}$. In your example, the groups are all different, but isomorphic.

Comment: I think your question is unnatural. Given any set $X$, you can match it the free group of basis $X$. Since the class of all sets is not a set, saying "the set of all groups" has no sense; moreover, under the background of cardinal theory, the class of all groups has no cardinality.

Comment: There is no **set** of all groups. It's too big. Do you mean "set of all subgroups of $(\Bbb R, +)$" ??

Comment: Anyway no the proof is almost there. You should state what you've shown: $x\mapsto \langle x \rangle \cap (0,1]$ is an injection from $(0,1]$ into the set of all subgroups of $(\Bbb R,+)$ {*not* modded out by isomorphism}. So now, is the conclusion true?

Comment: What is the set of all sub group of R ? Why there is no set of all group?

Comment: subgroups of $\Bbb R$, not just any old $R$, sorry.

Comment: Here is an answer to a question that was not asked: For every subset $S=\{p_1,\dots,\}$ of the primes, there exists a countable group $G(S)=\bigoplus_{p\in S}\mathbf C_p$. Two such groups  will be isomorphic iff their sets of primes coincide. So there is an uncountable number of countable groups.

Answer (score 2):

The collection of all groups is very large. Saying it's "uncountable" is an understatement: for any infinite size (cardinality) of set in the mathematical universe, there is a group that large. No two groups of different sizes can even be isomorphic, much less identical. This collection is too big to form a set, given the systems of set theory that math is done in. It's what's called a *proper class*.

In a comment, Angel Valencia mentions the free group on a(ny) set $X$ of generators. You can recover $X$ from the free group on $X$. So the class of all groups is as big as the class of all sets. (There is no *set* of all sets: assuming that there is leads quickly to Russell's paradox, a contradiction, so there isn't any such *set*.)